# How to keep only specific rows from a dataframe in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with 200 indices. I want to delete all the rows belonging to other indices except those belonging to certain indices like 128, 133, 140, 143, 199.

Previously, I dropped all the rows belonging to the indices 128, 133, 140, 143, 199, and it had worked fine. My code was

```
dataset_drop = dataset.drop(index = [128, 133, 140, 143, 199])
```

Now, I am trying to do the other way round. I want to keep the rows belonging to the indices 128, 133, 140, 143, 199 and delete the others.

What I tried doing:

```
dropped_data = dataset.drop(index != [128, 133, 140, 143, 199])
```

When I do this, I get an error saying

```
NameError: name 'index' is not defined
```

Can anyone tell what is it that I am doing wrong?

Comment: `index` is a named argument to the `drop` function. You can use `arg = some_value` to specify named arguments. The not equals here doesn't make sense. The interpreter is looking for a variable named `index` to compare against the list but as the error indicates, this variable is not defined.

Comment: Understood the mistake I was doing. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To explain the reason for your exception, the expression

```
index != [128, 133, 140, 143, 199]
```

Is evaluated as a conditional expression, rather than treating `index` as a keyword argument. Python searches for the variable `index` to compare against the list. Since `index` is not defined, you see a `NameError`.

---

Use `Index.difference` to fix your `drop` solution:

```
dataset.drop(index=df.index.difference([128, 133, 140, 143, 199]))
```

Or, even more idiomatically, you should use `loc` to *select* if you have positive labels.

```
dataset.loc[[128, 133, 140, 143, 199]]
# If they are indexes,
# dataset.iloc[[128, 133, 140, 143, 199]]
```

Answer (score 0):

As @pault said, you can't use a comparison (!=) here because index is a named argument. What I would do here is create a list of all the indices, for example:

```
indices = list(range(0, 200))
```

Then remove the ones you want to keep:

```
for x in [128, 133, 140, 143, 199]:
    indices.remove(x)
```

Now you have a list of all the indices you want to remove:

```
dropped_data = dataset.drop(index=indices)
```